# i keep getting syntax errors c#

Tags: c#, database, syntax

I'm doing a music database program and i have added buttons to update the database through the program. eg: edit / new track / delete. but it keeps dragging up syntax errors making the updates only temporary.

my update code is:

```
private void UpdateDB()
{
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myAdapter.Update(myDataTable);
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in UpdateDB : \r\n" + ex.Message);
```

but its bringing up this error (using the delete button):

[image]

Comment: We can't guess how the query is formed.

Comment: You need to show the full query and give some info on what database system you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You need to somehow escape column names with spaces in them. I think it depends on the DBMS you are using, but usually, you either have to use double quotes or square brackets:

```
"Artists Name" = ?
```

or

```
[Artists Name] = ?
```